# convert messy list of full user names and details to simple samAccountname with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Using an online javascript regex tool, I am trying to convert this:

```
john doe (vp of ops) [cupertino,CA,USA]
Expand/Contract Sally Jones (Systems Administrator) [San Antonio,TX,USA]
donald duck (vp of ops) [cupertino,CA,USA].
```

into this:

```
jdoe, SJones, dduck
```

so far I have only this, which selects some of text I want to omit:
(demo):  https://regex101.com/r/qH8sN2/5

regex:

```
\(.*[(.*?\[\]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use capture groups to capture the first initial and last name from the two words before the parenthesis, then copy those to the replacement.

Replace:

```
^.*\b(\w)\w*\s(\w+)\s\(.*$
```

with:

```
$1$2,
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/3VYBsJ/1)